# Quais são as opções para inicializar uma variável final em uma classe Java?

Tags: java

Dada a classe abaixo, quais são as opções de inicialização da variável `ANGLE`, visto que `final` pode ser inicializada somente uma vez?

```
class Triangle {
    public int base;
    public int height;
    private final double ANGLE;
}
```

Comment: construtores? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A melhor forma é a de se utilizar um construtor para isso:

```
class Triangle {
    public int base;
    public int height;
    private final double angle;

    public Triangle(double angle) {
        this.angle = angle;
    }
}
```

Outras formas menos interessantes seriam:

- Inicializar com atribuição direta:

  ```
  private final double angle = 60.0;
  ```

  Mas esta forma não é lá muito interessante, porque neste caso você poderia colocar o modificador `static` nela, vez que todas as instâncias vão receber o mesmo valor. Entretanto, mesmo assim dá para fazer cada instância receber um valor diferente:

  ```
  private final double angle = Math.random() * 180.0;
  ```

  Um exemplo mais complexo:

  ```
  private static int instanciasCriadas = 0;
  private final numeroDestaInstancia = ++instanciasCriadas;
  ```
- Utilizar um inicializador de instância:

  ```
  private final double angle;

  {
      angle = Math.random() * 180.0;
  }
  ```

Entretanto, o uso do construtor acaba sendo a forma mais limpa e versátil de se fazer isso. Em especial, usar inicializadores de instância é algo que ocorre muito raramente na prática. As duas únicas vantagens que o bloco de inicialização de instância pode ter sobre as demais formas que eu vislumbro são:

1. Um caso muito específico que consiste de uma combinação de fatores onde: (a) há um monte de construtores diferentes; (b) a lógica de atribuição de pelo menos um dos campos é a mesma independente do construtor utilizado e não depende de nenhum dos parâmetros do construtor ou de qualquer coisa que rode dentro dele e (c) os passos para se inicializar não são coisas que podem ser representadas apenas com uma simples expressão.
2. Inicialização de campos de classes anônimas que tem superclasses, quando a mesma precisa utilizar alguns métodos em sua inicialização.

Ambos os casos são muito especiais, representando *code smells* e é sempre possível refatorar-se as coisas para evitá-los.

Note que coloquei `angle` com letras minúsculas, e não maiúsculas. O motivo é que para ser considerado uma constante e então ser escrito com letras maiúsculas, a convenção diz que a variável tem que ser `static final`, e não apenas `final` (há outras regras além disso, mas já começa aí).

Por fim, o compilador vai mover por debaixo dos panos, todas as atribuições diretas a campos não `static`, bem como os blocos de inicialização de instância, para dentro do construtor. Depois disso, ele vai analisar o código do construtor resultante para certificar-se que todas os campos `final` recebem um valor até o término da execução do construtor e que só o recebem uma única vez, dando um erro de compilação em caso contrário (mais de uma atribuição ou possível não-atribuição). Essa verificação feita pelo compilador **quase sempre** garante que esses campos só poderão ser usados quando devidamente inicializados.

Por que *quase sempre*? Por que há uma forma de se furar isso ao invocar-se métodos que manipulam esses campos de dentro do construtor ou do bloco inicializador de instância antes deles terem sido inicializados:

```
class Ruim {

    private final int sempreTres;

    public Ruim() {
        mostra();
        sempreTres = 3;
    }

    public void mostra() {
        System.out.println(sempreTres);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ruim r = new Ruim();
        r.mostra();
    }
}
```

Eis a saída que isso gera:

```
0
3
```

[Veja aqui no ideone.](http://ideone.com/nuJkdT)